# Angular adding service to constructor causing no content display

Tags: angular

Whenever im trying to addd service in some component's constructor content of this component doesns't display.

My simple service looks like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { News } from 'src/app/interfaces/news';
    
@Injectable(
{providedIn: 'root'}
) 
export class NewsService {  
     public newsUrl = 'some url';
     
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {    }
     
     public getNews(): Observable<News[]> {
         console.log(this.newsUrl);
         return this.http.get<News[]>(this.newsUrl+'/news/all');   
    }
}
```

Im not even using it, just passing in constructor like this:

> export class TestComponent ...
>
> constructor(private newsService: NewsService) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure do you import in your module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

source [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#setup-for-server-communication)